# How to find number of rows column-wise while parsing an excel sheet

Tags: perl

I have an excel sheet where there are two columns. Column 1 has 5 rows and Column 2 has 2 rows.

```
Column 1   Column 2

Alpha      One
Beta       Two
Charlie
Gamma
Zeta
```

How can I get the maximum number of rows in Column 1 and Column 2.

I have the below code to get the maximum number of rows in the sheet.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;

my $FILE = "<excel file name>.xls";
my $SHEETNAME = "<sheet name>";

my $COLUMN1 = 1;
my $COLUMN2 = 2;

my $excel = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Workbook->Parse($FILE);
my $sheet = $excel->Worksheet($SHEETNAME);

$row_max = $sheet->{MaxRow};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably not the best solution, but it works:

```
my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $workbook = $parser->parse('<excel file name>.xls');

if ( !defined $workbook ) {
    die $parser->error(), ".\n";
}

for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheets() ) {
    my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
    my $cells_col2 = 0;

    for my $row ($row_min..$row_max){
        if (!defined $worksheet->get_cell( $row, 1 )) { # 1 == col-2
            last;
        }
        $cells_col2++;
    }
    print $cells_col2; # 2
}
```

loop stops when it finds the first empty cell in this column